# Dropzone uploads only first image

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I am using [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) plugin.But it remembers the path of only first image. If I drop 5 image files in dropzone. It will save first file 5 times.

My HTML code is:

```
<form id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone" action="@Url.Action("FileUploadHandler", "Electronics")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="adId" value="1076" />
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <div id="dropzonePreview" style="color:white" class="dz-default dz-message">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="abc" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit this form!</button>
</form>
```

My js code is:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { 
                autoProcessQueue: false,
                uploadMultiple: true,
                parallelUploads: 100,
                maxFiles: 100,
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                clickable:'#dropzonePreview',
                init: function () {
                    var myDropzone = this;
                    this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        myDropzone.processQueue();
                    });
               }
       }
```

My MVC function is:

```
public ActionResult FileUploadHandler()
        {
            int adid =int.Parse( Request["adId"] );
            var name = Request["name"];
            int count = 1;
            var imaa = db.AdImages.ToList();
            foreach (var img in imaa)
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(@"~\Images\Ads\" + adid + "_" + count++ + img.imageExtension));
            }
            count = 1;
            foreach (var fileKey in Request.Files.AllKeys)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[fileKey];
                try
                {
                    if (file != null)
                    {
                        HttpPostedFileBase file1 = file;
                        string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file1.FileName);
                        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Ads/" + adid + "_" + count++ + extension));
                        AdImage image = new AdImage();
                        image.imageExtension = extension;
                        image.adId = adid;
                        db.AdImages.Add(image);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Json(new { Message = "Error in saving file" });
                }
            }
            return Json(new { Message = "File saved" });
        }
```

What I am doing wrong? why it saves only first image `n` times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is is posting back multiple files with the same name so `Request.Files.AllKeys` contains a collection where the keys are all the same value so that `var file = Request.Files[fileKey];` always gets the first file.

Change your code to

```
for(int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
  HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
  string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
  ....
}
```

Alternatively, change you method to

```
public ActionResult FileUploadHandler(int adId, string name, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> ###)
{
  ....
  foreach(HttpPostedFileBase file in ###)
  {
    ....
  }
}
```

where `###` is the name attribute of the file input your generating (i.e. the value you are currently seeing in `Request.Files.AllKeys`

so that all parameters are correctly bound and you do not need to use `Request]`. Even better, use a view model containing these 3 properties and strongly bind to you model so that you also get validation.